# Converting jstring to c++ string results to error in java code execution

Tags: java, c++, string, dll, java-native-interface

I am passing a java object to c++ via jni, which has a string as a attribute in it.
I try to convert it into a string, in order to pass that variable to a c++ constructor.

Java Class

```
import at.xxxx.calculatorhuman.HumanBean;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("library: "
                + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

        CalculatorController calcController = new CalculatorController();
        HumanController humanController = new HumanController();

        HumanBean human = new HumanBean("John Doe", 16, 3000, 2988.77);
        int ageOfHuman = humanController.getAgeOfHuman(human);
    }
}
```

HumanBean.java

```
package at.xxxx.calculatorhuman;

public class HumanBean {

    String name;
    int alter;
    int gehalt;
    double gehaltDouble;

    public HumanBean(String name, int alter, int gehalt, double gehaltDouble) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.alter = alter;
        this.gehalt = gehalt;
        this.gehaltDouble = gehaltDouble;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAlter() {
        return alter;
    }
    public void setAlter(int alter) {
        this.alter = alter;
    }
    public int getGehalt() {
        return gehalt;
    }
    public void setGehalt(int gehalt) {
        this.gehalt = gehalt;
    }
    public double getGehaltDouble() {
        return gehaltDouble;
    }
    public void setGehaltDouble(double gehaltDouble) {
        this.gehaltDouble = gehaltDouble;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HumanBean [name=" + name + ", alter=" + alter + ", gehalt=" + gehalt + ", gehaltDouble=" + gehaltDouble
                + "]";
    }
}
```

C++ File

```
/*
 * Class:     HumanController
 * Method:    getAgeOfHuman
 * Signature: (LHumanBean;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_HumanController_getAgeOfHuman(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jobject objarg) {
    std::cout << "-------------------------Java_HumanController_getAgeOfHuman---------------------------" << endl;
    jclass cls = (*env).GetObjectClass(objarg);

    /////////////////////////////////
    jfieldID fidName = (*env).GetFieldID(cls, "name", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    std::cout << "First Line Finished  - jfieldID = " << fidName << endl;
    jstring nameStringJNI = (jstring)(*env).GetObjectField(cls, fidName);
    std::cout << "Second Line Finished - jstring = " << nameStringJNI << endl;
    const char* raw = env->GetStringUTFChars(nameStringJNI, NULL);
    std::cout << "Third Line Finished - raw = " << raw << endl;
    std::string str = std::string(raw);
    std::cout << "Fourth Line Finished - str = " << str << endl;
    std::cout << "Java_HumanController_getAgeOfHuman c++ Name " << str << endl;
    /////////////////////////////////
    Human humanMirror = createHuman(str, age, gehaltInt, gehaltDouble);
    return humanMirror.alter;
}
```

[image: Console Output of Java program]

As you can see, it only compiles the first two lines - after that it throws the error message. ( it throws at `const char* raw = env->GetStringUTFChars(nameStringJNI, NULL);`)

I tried already many various solution to convert a jstring to string, as my constructor im using does not accept a jstring as an argument. Every solution I tried lead to the same error.

What is causing this error and how to fix it ?

Comment: You are again calling `GetObjectField` with a `cls` argument instead of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ code is implemented incorrectly, in particular your call to `(*env).GetObjectField()` is wrong.  The `HumanBean.name` field is not a `static` field, so you need to pass it a pointer to the `HumanBean` *object instance* (which is in the `objarg` parameter) as the object to read the `name` field from.  But you are passing it a pointer to the `HumanBean` *class type* instead (from the `cls` variable you are extracting from `objarg`), causing `GetObjectField()` to return a NULL pointer that you are not handling.

Try this instead:

```cpp
/*
 * Class:     HumanController
 * Method:    getAgeOfHuman
 * Signature: (LHumanBean;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_HumanController_getAgeOfHuman(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jobject objarg)
{
    std::cout << "-------------------------Java_HumanController_getAgeOfHuman---------------------------" << std::endl;

    if (!objarg) {
        std::cout << "objarg is null!" << std::endl;
        return -1; // or env->Throw() an exception...
    }

    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(objarg);
    // TODO: verify that objarg is really an instance of the
    // "at.xxxx.calculatorhuman.HumanBean" class before doing
    // anything with it...

    /////////////////////////////////
    jfieldID fidName = env->GetFieldID(cls, "name", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    std::cout << "First Line Finished  - jfieldID = " << fidName << std::endl;
    if (!fidName) {
        std::cout << "Could not find objarg.name field!" << std::endl;
        return -1; // or env->Throw() an exception...
    }

    jstring nameStringJNI = (jstring) env->GetObjectField(objarg, fidName); // <-- use objarg, not cls!
    std::cout << "Second Line Finished - jstring = " << nameStringJNI << std::endl;
    if (!nameStringJNI) {
        std::cout << "Could not get pointer to objarg.name field!" << std::endl;
        return -1; // or env->Throw() an exception...
    }

    // NOTE: Java uses *modified* UTF-8! Consider using env->GetStringChars()
    // with std::wstring instead... 
    const char* raw = env->GetStringUTFChars(nameStringJNI, NULL);
    std::cout << "Third Line Finished - raw = " << (const void*)raw << std::endl;
    if (!raw) {
        std::cout << "Could not get pointer to objarg.name content!" << std::endl;
        return -1; // or env->Throw() an exception...
    }

    std::string str(raw); // <-- can't construct std::string with a NULL pointer!
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(nameStringJNI, raw); // <-- avoid a memory leak!
    std::cout << "Fourth Line Finished - str = " << str << endl;
    std::cout << "Java_HumanController_getAgeOfHuman c++ Name " << str << endl;
    /////////////////////////////////

    Human humanMirror = createHuman(str, age, gehaltInt, gehaltDouble);
    return humanMirror.alter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: jni.h]

In my `jni.h` (Fedora 29), `jstring` is defined as a pointer to `_jstring` struct.
As in your result, `nameStringJNI` was printed as 000000 = NULL pointer.